# Pyramid: what is the analog of php's $_FILES['Filedata']['file_name']?

Tags: python, pyramid

I need to know it to correctly get filedata from POST dictionary.

I want to use [Agile Uploader](http://www.webappers.com/2010/04/09/agile-uploader-resize-images-before-uploading/) (resizes images on client side before upload on the server) in my project. It has process.php file as example of handling image on server. In that file:

```
$tmp_name = $_FILES["Filedata"]["file_name"];     // where "tmp_name" is file name
```

As Pyramid doesn't have `FILES` dictionary, I supose I have to find image in `POST`. But when I try to upload image `POST` is empty...

So where it send that image and how to find it on server side?

HTML (most part of html code taken from their [demo](http://www.shift8creative.com/agile-uploader/examples/single.php)):

```
<form action="/test" method="post" id="singularDemo" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div id="single"></div>
</form>

<a href="#" onClick="document.getElementById('agileUploaderSWF').submit();">Submit</a>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#single').agileUploaderSingle({
        submitRedirect:'',
        formId:'singularDemo',
        progressBarColor:'#3b5998',
        flashVars:{
            firebug:true,
            form_action:'/test'
        }
    });
</script>
```

Python (Pyramid code), just for testing - simple view:

```
def test(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        pass

    return {}
```

Thanks!

Comment: post your html and python code.

Comment: @soulcheck - added html and python code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the `$_FILES` global contains files submitted by a `POST` request, you can access them using `request.POST`:

```
# access the filename
filename = request.POST['Filedata'].filename

# access the actual file
input_file = request.POST['Filedata'].file
```

This is an exact equivalent of the PHP `$_FILES` variable, so if it doesn't work, something else must be wrong.

The Pyramid cookbook has [more information](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid_cookbook/en/latest/forms/file_uploads.html) about file uploads.